# adding two filters at django admin and having two query results (for comparison)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

[image]

This layout is what I want to achieve. e.g I want to compare query results in two date range 1/1 ~ 2/1 and 5/1 ~ 6/1. How can I do this? I am using Django 1.11.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following format to achieve your requirement:

```
from django.db.models import Q
queryset = yourmodel.objects.filter(Q(startdate__gth=date1,startdate__lt=date2) | Q(startdate__gth=date3,startdate__lt=date4))
```

Comment: this just give a 'OR'. and what I want is NOT combining two query results but having them separately so that I can 'visual' compare.

Comment: then you can go for two different django queries... what is difficult in that?

Comment: I want to run the query through 'filter'. In filter 1, I select date 1/1~1/3, in filter 2, I select date 2/1~2/3, but the problem is the date in filter 2 is never passed to backend.